# Obtaining a travel visa to the UK for a Syrian living and working abroad

Tags: visas, uk, syrian-citizens

A friend and I (I am British) are hoping to give a presentation at a conference in the UK next May.  My friend is on a Syrian passport.  We are both living and working in Saudi Arabia at present.

What kind of visa does he need to get into the country, and where should we go to apply for it?

Comment: What sort of conference? Will you be paid for giving the presentation?

Comment: I've removed the 'how difficult will it be' as this is subjective (see [help] - subjective questions get closed as off-topic) and depends on so many factors that we couldn't possibly know.  Good luck!

Comment: You need to disclose your friend's status in KSA and their returnability.